# I have inf values in a dataset column that don't see like inf at all

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, sum, infinite

I have this operation:

`df['netPCR'] = df['ValorNeto'] / df.index.map(PCR['ValorNeto'])`

`df['netPCR'] = df['netPCR'].fillna(0)`

But some how when

`df['netPCR'].sum()`

It results in inf and when I try to get what values are inf things just get weird.

[image]

What do you think it is happening and how to fix it?

I tried to round values or convert them to objects, but the problem is not fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like division by 0 is returning infinity and not nan. You can use `df.replace`:

```
df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], 0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: It seems to work fine, thank you QWERYL!!! But I'm still wondering why np.isinf detect those values like inf

Comment: @LuisJaramilloOrozco I'm glad to help! Feel free to mark this answer as correct if it answered the question.